SysML IBD diagram - Is it legal to connect a port to multiple ports?
Using sysml 1.6
In an IBD diagram, can I connect one port to multiple ports (*1)
(i.e., with two connectors coming out the same port)
?
E.g., I have an IBD diagram with 3 parts: A, B, and C; and each part has a port p. So we have: A.p, B.p and C.p.
Can I legally connect A.p to both B.p and C.p?
I.e., two connectors coming out of the port A.p.
(Just because my SysML platform (EA) allows it, does not mean it is legal...)
(To compare with an activity diagram: you cannot legally have two objects flows coming out of a single pin. You have to add a fork element to create the multiple parallel object flow.)
This seems to be a basic ABC thing that must have been asked a 1000 times, but I can't find it.
Thanks
Edit
Note *1: "Can I connect one port to multiple ports"
i.e., one O/P port outputs the same data item to multiple I/P ports.

Since IBD diagrams do not have a fork element, then allowing one port to output to  multiple ports seems to me to make more sense then having two ports outputting the same data item.

Follow-on question: And where is the source in the SysML v1.6 spec?

Yes, it is allowed to connect one port to multiple other ports. This is what UML says about it:

UML 2.5.1: If several Connectors are attached on one side of a Port, then any
request arriving at this Port on a link derived from a Connector on
the other side of the Port will be forwarded on links corresponding to
these Connectors. It is not defined whether these requests will be
forwarded on all links, or on only one of those links.

SysML doesn't change this.
The Precise Semantics for Composite structures defines a good default strategy:

PSCS 1.2: If the request concerns the emission of a Signal and there are multiple possible targets, the signal is broadcasted to all
the targets. If the request concerns an Operation call and there are
multiple possible targets, the call is propagated to the first target.

Now, in SysML we also have flow properties and the specification says about its semantics:

SysML 1.7: Flow due to flow properties can only occur when flow properties match.[…] The flow property semantics above applies to each
connector of a block usage, including when the block usage has
multiple connectors [italics by me].

Of course, what really happens depends on the kind of thing flowing. If it is information it can be broadcast. If it is matter or energy, it needs to be somehow divided up, so that it is conserved. How this is done is not defined in SysML.
Please note, if A is connected to B and C, B and C will also be connected. The term "connector" is often misunderstood to be some kind of part, such as a pipe. Maybe a better name would have been "connection". To cite again UML:

When there are multiple connectors attached to a single
ConnectableElement, the semantics are the same as a single n-ary
Connector connecting the ConnectableElement to all of the
ConnectableElements connected via the multiple  connectors.

PS: It is allowed to have multiple object flows outgoing from one pin. It means that it is not determined, which flow will get the object token.

Thank you for the response.
What would be an alternative and better way of modeling a part A that sends/receives the same data with two other parts B and C.?
To have two ports? That's it? If so, makes a bit of a mess on the diagram.
Thanks

Why do you want another way? For data it is quite clear as you modeled it, since it is easy to copy data. So connecting one port of A to B and C means that both B and C get their own copy of the data. Please note, that the flow property  doesn't specify, whether the data are being pushed or pulled. So it could as well be the receiver that  grabs the data.


" ...  It means that it is not determined, which flow will get the object token."


"Why do you want another way? "

Because what you said about not deterministic tokens worried me. It made me thing again that I was doing illegal SysML.
I did not realize that token flows are relevant to static diagrams, i.e.,  that tokens flow between blocks.
I thought that tokens flow only in behavior diagrams, i.e.,  between actions (via the actions' pins).


"So connecting one port of A to B and C means that both B and C get their own copy of the data. "

So what I did is good -then -- Correct?

yes, it is good.
